# Put nth-child in a var

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

You can put a variable inside nth-child like so:

```
var myVar = $(elem);
$("div:nth-child(" + myVar + ")");
```

But how can you put the value of nth-child inside a var? I don't think that nth-child is the appropriate term, but I don't know what else to call it. **I mean: get which child the element is and put it in a var.**

For instance, take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/KFXnN/):
**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
</div>

<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        thisNumber = // which child is it? as a numeric value;

        $("p:nth-child(" + thisNumber + ")").toggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this :) , you don't need any variables, just `$(this).index()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KFXnN/1/)

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(" + $(this).index() + ")").toggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: I completely forgot about index. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[`$(this).index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Sometimes, the solution is a lot simpler than you think ;)

Comment: I completely forgot about `index`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("p:nth-child(" + $(this).index() + ")").toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KFXnN/3/

Comment: I completely forgot about index. Thanks!